# Matplotlib ax.fill_between fills above, instead of below

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to use `ax.fill_between` to plot the area under a curve, but for some odd reason, one curve gets plotted just fine, and the other one isn't, what goes wrong?

Code:

```py
_, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 7))

sns.lineplot(x1, y1)
ax.fill_between(x1, y1, alpha=0.3)
sns.lineplot(x2, y2)
ax.fill_between(x2, y2, alpha=0.3)
```

Result:

[image: Errored plot]

I've tried also `ax.fill_between(x2, y2, 0, alpha=0.3)` and `ax.fill_between(x2, 0, y2, alpha=0.3)` but I get the same plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this can happen if the data isn't sorted. To give an example, consider a dataset where the very first x value is identical to the last,

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(346)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 50, 51)
x[0] = x[-1]
y = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(51))+6


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.fill_between(x,y, alpha=0.3)

plt.show()
```

[image]

So obviously it can be solved by sorting the data first. E.g.,

```
ind = np.argsort(x)
x=x[ind]
y=y[ind]
```

[image]